# Textarea selected when user-select is set to none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a textarea in which user selection is set to none for all elements using the css

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none; 
-webkit-user-select: none; 
-khtml-user-select: none; 
-moz-user-select: none; 
-ms-user-select: none; 
user-select: none;
```

In the below example. I made a mouse down on the word **how are** and move the mouse over the textarea on the mousedown state. Here the textarea becomes selected and it becomes in focus state. when i just type a character it, start typing event though it is in **user-select: none** state. It happens only in chrome. How to prevent this?

I just want to prevent the textarea becomes focus when i mouse down in some other area and move the mouse over the text area i don't want it to become focusable.

```css
* {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; 
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
     -khtml-user-select: none; 
       -moz-user-select: none; 
        -ms-user-select: none; 
            user-select: none; 
                               
}
```

```html
Hello
<textarea>Software Developement is the job i love</textarea>
How are you
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here, but if you don't want the `textarea` to be editable, just add the `readonly` attribute to it in HTML

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I just want to prevent the textarea becomes focus when i mouse down in some other area and move the mouse over the text area i don't want it to become focusable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Chrome's known bug, see here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=340671

**Issue:** 340671

**Title:** Textarea with -webkit-user-select:none should not be selectable

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following code

```
<textarea readonly>
Software Developement is the job i love
</textarea>
```

prevent Mousedown on textarea

```
$('textarea').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: how to make the interactive ie. i want the textarea to be editable. But not become focussed when I move the mouse over the textarea on the mousedown state.

Comment: @Ashokkumar please Upvote & mark it correct answer, If this works. Thanks

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` will prevent textarea to do anything, even typing into it.